# Best practice to pass attribute from ModelForm.clean() to Model.save()

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if getattr(self, 'my_attr', False):
            # do things


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self)
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if self.has_changed():
            self.instance.my_attr = self.get_the_needed_info()
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields ='__all__'


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = MyForm
```

During `MyModel.save()`, I need to check for a condition that is evaluated in `ModelForm.clean()`.

During `clean()`, I assign the attribute `my_attr` to `self.instance`.

- It is working
- it seems to be
  [thread-safe](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c2250cfb80e27cdf8d098428824da2800a18cadf/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1521-L1522)
  (within an atomic transaction).

Is there any reason I miss, that urges a refactoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user), using the `ModelForm` to set an existing instance attribute, is recommended.

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```